# Android GPS not working anymore

Tags: android, gps

I was playing around with the GPS on my HTC Desire S and made a very small map application. It was working very well, until I stumbled upon [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps).
I uninstalled it again and now my GPS is not working anymore. I know that there is the fix-time, but

```
locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
```

ALWAYS returns true, and the app isn't requesting location-updates anymore.

GPSMapTrackerService.java:

```
package net.hobbycoder.android.gpsmap;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSMapTrackerService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private Resources res;
    private FileManager fileManager;
    private LocationManager locManager;
    private boolean showNotification = true;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        res = getResources();
        fileManager = new FileManager(getApplicationContext());
        locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //GPS on?
        if(!locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            Toast.makeText(this, res.getString(R.string.noGPSText), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showNotification = false;
            stopSelf();
        }
        else{
            showNotification = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startID) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        if(showNotification)
            Toast.makeText(this, res.getString(R.string.startedText), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        locManager.removeUpdates(this);
        if(showNotification)
            Toast.makeText(this, res.getString(R.string.stoppedText), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        fileManager.write(loc.getLatitude() + ":" + loc.getLongitude() + ";");
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}
```

It seems as if the location got stuck, because the text under my clock widget is saying I am in New York, but I am in Germany.

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest) is also not working, so the problem shouldn't be in my code.

Hope anyone can help :(

Answer (score 0):

[Service.onStart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) is deprecated and if you read the preferred [Service.onStartCommand()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) documentation you'll see that depending on your API onStart() might not even be called.

Try changing onStart() to onStartCommand():

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    if(showNotification)
        Toast.makeText(this, res.getString(R.string.startedText), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Also** you never call the `super` function in *any* of your overridden methods. Update all of them (except onBind() which does nothing):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ...

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    if(showNotification)
        Toast.makeText(this, res.getString(R.string.startedText), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

// etc, etc
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips. But it is still not working. It seems as if the location got stuck (see question).

Comment: Hmm, did you turn on mock locations? (Settings -> Applications -> Development -> Allow Mock Locations)

Comment: I turned it off, rebooted my device but it is still not working.

Comment: Ok, re-read the developer's app description, there is a section on disabling "Use Wireless Networks" because it inadvertently keeps the fake location around.

Comment: The widget displays the real place now, but the GPS apps are still not requesting updates

Comment: I don't see any more documentation on this app... Have you rebooted and double checked that the GPS is enabled?

Comment: Reboot wasn't enough. I did a hard reboot and now it's working. :) Nevertheless, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [GPS Status & Toobox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&hl=en) app to clear the GPS data and redownload it. I don't have the app currently, but it's somewhere in the menu options.